# Change Product Addon price based on select Variation

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I am running WooCommerce and WooCommerce Product Add-ons.

Is there a way on a Variable product to have the price of an addon be different based on the selected Variation?

**Example:**

**Three Size Variations:**

10m | 25m | 50m

**Extra confetti addon:**

10m size: £3

25m size: £30

50m size: £300

Comment: If you check on the page for the plugin, it states that "Product Add-Ons work both globally and on a product level. Add-ons cannot be defined for individual variations conditionally." See https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/ . But if anybody knows a way to do this, I'd be very interested to hear the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This plugin can fit: https://support.rightpress.net/hc/en-us/categories/200133263

There is a lot of diferent logics you can use it to change the price depend of.